# System.out.println() shows ProductDirectory@647e05 and Product List :[]

Tags: java

I have four classes.

- `Supplier` which has `name`, `id`.
- `SupplierDirectory` which has `Arraylist` of type `Supplier`.
- `Product` which has `name`.
- `ProductDirectory` with `ArrayList` of type `Product`.

**Product.java**

```
public class Product {
      //private int productId;
       private String productName;
   
   

       /* public int getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }
     */
    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

        public void setProductName(String productName) {
           this.productName = productName;
      }

         /*     public int getPrice() {
           return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public boolean isAvailability() {
        return availability;
    }

    public void setAvailability(boolean availability) {
        this.availability = availability;
    }*/
    
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return productName;
    }
   
            
    
       
}
```

**ProductDirectory.java**

```
    public class ProductDirectory {
    
    private ArrayList<Product> prodDir = new ArrayList<Product>();
   

     public ArrayList<Product> getProdDir() {
        return prodDir;
           }

    public void setProdDir(ArrayList<Product> prodDir) {
        this.prodDir = prodDir;
    }
    public Product addProduct()
    {
        Product prod = new Product();
        prodDir.add(prod);
        return prod;
    }
    
   }
```

**Supplier.java**

```
public class Supplier {

String supplierName;
private ProductDirectory proddirectory = new ProductDirectory();

public String getSupplierName() {
    return supplierName;
}

public void setSupplierName(String supplierName) {
    this.supplierName = supplierName;
}

public ProductDirectory getProddirectory() {
    return proddirectory;
}

public void setProddirectory(ProductDirectory proddirectory) {
    this.proddirectory = proddirectory;
}
}
```

**SupplierDirectory.java**

```
    public class SupplierDirectory {
    private ArrayList<Supplier> supplierDir = new ArrayList<Supplier>();

    public ArrayList<Supplier> getSupplierDir() {
        return supplierDir;
    }

    public void setSupplierDir(ArrayList<Supplier> supplierDir) {
        this.supplierDir = supplierDir;
    }
     
    public Supplier addsupplier()
    {
        Supplier sup = new Supplier();
        supplierDir.add(sup);
        return sup;
    }
    
    public void deleteSupplier(Supplier sup)
    {
        //Supplier sup = new Supplier();
        supplierDir.remove(sup);
    }
}
```

Following is my main method.

```
public static void main (String[] args){
   
                    int i ,j;
                String supplierName;
                String productName;
                SupplierDirectory supDir = new SupplierDirectory();
                ProductDirectory prodDir = new ProductDirectory();
                Product p;
                Supplier Sup = new Supplier();
               Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);             
               for (i = 0; i<=2; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter Supplier to add");
                    supplierName =  user_input.next();
                     supDir.addsupplier();
                    for (j=0;j<=3;j++)
                    {
                System.out.println("Enter Product to add"); 
                productName =  user_input.next();
                prodDir.addProduct();
                System.out.println("You have entered Product"+ prodDir); 
               System.out.println("Product List :"+ Sup.getProddirectory().getProdDir());
                  }              
                }
                
               // Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("You have entered "+ userInput()); 
                
                System.out.println("You have entered "+ userInput());
                supDir.addsupplier();
                
                System.out.println("Suppliers  "+ supDir.getSupplierDir());
       
            }
    
    public static String userInput ()
    {
          String supplierName;
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter Supplier to add"); 
        supplierName =  user_input.next();
        return supplierName;
    }
    
           }
```

After I run this I get following result:

> Enter Supplier to add
>
> Abc
>
> Enter Product to add
>
> dell
>
> You have entered ProductBusiness.ProductDirectory@647e05
>
> Product List :[]

How should I resolve this?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I need to display 5 suppliers with 10 products each

Comment: well, you definitely didn't enter 5 suppliers or 10 products here.

Comment: Part of your problem is this line: `System.out.println("You have entered Product"+ prodDir);`. You're printing out the `prodDir` object's `toString()` representation, not its contents. You'll have to iterate through the list and display each item manually.

Comment: @ LanguidSquid I know that, first I'm trying to display only two of them

Comment: well if you only want to display the two right now then you shouldn't say you want to display 5 and 10 :)

Comment: If you would like some more specific help, then I recommend you post the code for the `Supplier`, `Product`, `SupplierDirectory` and `ProductDirectory` classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change these lines:

```
prodDir.addProduct();
System.out.println("You have entered Product"+ prodDir); 
System.out.println("Product List :"+ Sup.getProddirectory().getProdDir());
```

to instead be:

```
Product newProduct = new Product();
newProduct.setName(productName);
prodDir.getProdDir().put(newProduct);
System.out.println("You have entered Product"+ Arrays.toString(prodDir.getProdDir().toArray())); 
Sup.setProddirectory(prodDir);
System.out.println("Product List :"+ Arrays.toString(Sup.getProddirectory().getProdDir().toArray()));
```

also add a new `toString()` method to your `Product` class like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

The `productDirectory` list from `Supplier` is always empty because you instantiate a new `Supplier` like this:

```
Supplier Sup = new Supplier();
```

but you never call  `.setProddirectory()`

you should add the line

```
Sup.setProddirectory(prodDir);
```

before the line

```
System.out.println("Product List :"+ Arrays.toString(Sup.getProddirectory().getProdDir().toArray()));
```

Comment: It still gives me    Enter Supplier to add
dell
Enter Product to add
dell
You have entered Product[null]
Product List :[]

Comment: @CRO If you would like some more specific help, then I recommend you post the code for the `Supplier`, `Product`, `SupplierDirectory` and `ProductDirectory` classes. I'll bet that you don't instantiate your product list object when you call `prodDir.addProduct()`.

Comment: @ LanguidSquid How should I share all the class file?

Comment: @ LanguidSquid ..thanks one of the code is working but product list is still   Product List :[]

Comment: It gives me following error                                                                   incompatible types: ArrayList<Product> cannot be converted to ProductDirectory

Comment: @CRO I misused the set method, I have edited the answer to contain the correct solution.